# Project Euler #3 in C# - largest prime factor

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge, primes

I just started doing the *Project Euler* challenges and right now I'm on Challenge #3 - The largest prime factor of 600851475143.

I wrote some code and tried to optimize it based on some other Stack Overflow users' advice.

What I got is this code which does its job, but I think it takes longer than it should - calculating high numbers like 600851475143 takes forever!

Am I in the right way? How could I optimize it?

```
using System;

namespace ProjectEuler_LargestPrimeFactor
{
    class Program
    {
        static long numberToFactor = 600851475143;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(LargestPrimeFactorOf(numberToFactor) + " is the largest prime factor of " + numberToFactor);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static long LargestPrimeFactorOf(long n)
        {
            long lastPrimeFactor = 0;

            for (long i = 2; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (isPrime(i) && n % i == 0)
                {
                    lastPrimeFactor = i;
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " is a prime factor of " + n);
                }
            }

            return lastPrimeFactor;
        }

        static bool isPrime(long n)
        {
            if (n == 2) return true;
            if ((n > 2 && n % 2 == 0) || n == 1) return false;

            for (long i = 2; i <= Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(n)); ++i)
            {
                if (n % i == 0) return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your implementation, it is taking exactly as long as it should :).  One of your loops is iterating n times: you should not be surprised that it takes forever to do 600 billion primality tests!  You need to fix your algorithm, and possibly do some learning on asymptotic analysis.

Comment: You don't need to test for primality to solve this puzzle btw.

Comment: In isPrime you still check twice if the number is dividable by multiplies of 2. First you check in the if statement if the number % 2 == 0, then you precede to check if the number is dividable by all even numbers. Don't check twice.  Start at 3, increment by 2. Mathematics will hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static bool isPrime(long n)
{
    if (n == 2) return true;
    if ((n > 2 && n % 2 == 0) || n == 1) return false;

    for (long i = 2; i <= Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(n)); ++i)
    {
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The above code is inefficient.

- performance: since `n` doesn't change, you should only compute `√n` once.
- performance: don't check even numbers in the `for` loop, since they will never divide evenly.
- readability: don't mix the `n == 1` case with the `n is even` case.
- naming: method names start with a capital letter.

Improved code:

```
static bool IsPrime(long n)
{
    if (n < 4) return n > 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) return false;

    long limit = (long) Math.Sqrt(n);
    for (long i = 5; i <= limit; i += 2)
    {
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look correct: limit will very often be smaller than the largest prime factor.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution to this problem

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        long num = 600851475143;
        int count = 3;
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while (num > 1)
        {
            if (num%count == 0)
            {
                num /= count;
            }
            else
            {
                count += 2;
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("The largest prime factor of the number {0} is {1} ", 600851475143, count);
        Console.WriteLine("Time to calculate in milliseconds : {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

First of all most of the exercises you will find on Project Euler will require some math formula or concept in order to achieve the highest possible performance. It's not pure programming and thus not the best place to practice it in my opinion (ofc assuming you don't know all the formulas) you will probably learn more math than programming in the process which is a good thing if that's what you are looking for. Long story short look for formula before you go into the programming.

Back to your actual code :

**Why is your code working slow ?** 
 There are few points here that I want to make first method calls are slower than just a bunch of code in a single method again some problems you will find later in Project Euler will be pretty easy to solve but hard to optimize so the usual C# code has everything separated in methods and classes because the performance loss is not that big in a normal project however here this might be your only bottleneck in some cases. You should always think in perspective what if you had even bigger number ? Would your method still work fast enough ? A working program doesn't mean that it's a good program.

Next you start thinking what can you improve and why exactly you are doing certain things. Do you really need to know every single number that is prime ?

In my solution there is simple prime factorization starting from the smallest prime we keep increasing the current number we have until we get a number that we can divide only by itself i.e the  largest prime factor. 100,000 iterations run for about 3000-3200 ms on my machine.

Comment: Nice. We both have the [same implementation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/143680/72772) though starting from 3 works for this case, it's not a generic solution for any number n

Comment: Yeah the approach is pretty much the same, however you have redundant variable and it's always best to start from 3 if necessary you can divide it manually outside of your loop just because starting from 3 allows you to have increment of +2 and that's why your current code is ~twice slower than mine.

Comment: Good point and yeah I don't need to store the `greatestFactor`. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @ParasDPain that's what code review is all about right ? Learning while you help someone else ^^.

Comment: @denis, To me a code review is mainly about reviewing the existing code, and not only to present a new solution. You mention why your solution differs, but I believe you could explain why the OPs is slow more extensively and thusly help them avoiding similar issues in the future.

Comment: @holroy I completely agree with you but I think that this line summarises all the problems in OP's code `You don't need to know all the prime numbers` It's basically working slow because he is checking every single number against `IsPrime()` but I will add some more info in the answer.

Comment: The OP solution is actually O(n^2), as they loop towards N in both methods, so your statement is part of the answer, but could be expanded upon. :-)

Comment: Breaks on any even number

Comment: @Paparazzi Please give an example.

Comment: Really you need and example of an even number?   8

Comment: It breaks only on numbers divisible by 2 since i skip it rest are alright if you read my discussion with Paras D Pain you will see i mention that problem.

Comment: If OP want to I can upload version which supports that.

Comment: So it only fails on 1/2 the cases.   You do not mention that *problem* to OP.

Comment: It wont fail on 12 or 14 for example it's just numbers that has the highest prime factor of 2. That's not 1/2 of the cases.

Comment: I've updated my [answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/143680/72772) as per the discussion in this thread :)

Comment: Nice. It is sound logic to not include 2, the number 600851475143 ends with 3, and can't have a factor 2, the maths add up. 

I like the condition while (num < count * count), and using the num better. Doesn't matter much in problem 3 but it will matter later. 3432 iterations is more than 738 iterations as per my condition vs yours. There is no need to check the numbers between 1471 and 6857. You will never for any number find the a factor over the sqrt of that number, if you can't find a factor smaller then the sqrt of that number.

Comment: The code breaks if the number has multiples of prime squares, like 3^2 or 5^2 or 7^2 or 3*5^2, that is more of interesting. You could replace if (num%count == 0) with while (num%count == 0), for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

minor

```
static bool isPrime(long n)
{
    if (n < 2)      return false;
    if (n <= 3)     return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
```

this is wrong

```
for (long i = 2; i <= Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(n)); ++i)
```

you should be starting on 5 and skipping by 2

see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

```
function is_prime(n : integer)
if n ≤ 1
    return false
else if n ≤ 3
    return true
else if n mod 2 = 0 or n mod 3 = 0
    return false
let i ← 5
while i×i ≤ n
    if n mod i = 0 or n mod (i + 2) = 0
        return false
    i ← i + 6
return true;
```

I identified the problem to Denis of even number fails in a comment but he declined to make a simple fix to his answer.
Solution:

```
long num = 600851475143;
long sqrt = (int)Math.Sqrt(num);
long count = 2;
while (num > 1)
{
    if (num % count == 0)
        num /= count;
    else
    {
        count ++;
        if(count % 2 == 0)
            count ++;
        if(count > 3 && count % 3 == 0)
            count += 2;
        if (count > sqrt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("number is prime ignore following line");
            break; // num is a prime
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("The largest prime factor of the number {0} is {1} ", num, count);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the _this is wrong_?

Comment: Why would you start at 2 and compare every value when you you have already eliminated even?

Comment: Ah, ok. I though the _this is wrong_ referred to the code above it. So the code above it is _minor_. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

The major algorithmic optimization can be done by removing the prime number test entirely. Simply finding the factors in order and exhausting each only produces primes. Here is some modified code for reference.

```
static long LargestPrimeFactorOf(long n)
{
    long factor = 2;
    Console.Write("Largest factor of {0} is: ", n);

    while (n > 1)
    {
        if (n % factor == 0)
        {
            n /= factor;
        }
        else
        {
            factor++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(factor);
}
```

As you can see, I'm simply recursively dividing by the number `factor` until it can't be perfectly divided anymore (this avoids false-positives by `factor`'s multiples). As a result only prime numbers are operated over our number `n`.

This algorithm takes on average **0.11 milliseconds** over 20,000 runs on an Intel i5 2.2GHz processor, 8GB RAM system.

Comment: It's cute to remember the largest factor this way.  However it's much less efficient than it could be when n is prime or divisible by a large prime, since it has to increment factor all the way to that prime.

Answer (score -1):

On the surface, everything looks alright to me, but that Console.WriteLine() in your for loop is going to add extra processing time since you are writing out to the screen quite a lot. Try commenting that line out to see if it improves the speed of your application.

Comment: This answer is of little use. Sure, commenting out the `Console.WriteLine()` will be better, but negligible and insignificant considering the much bigger performance issues of the posted code.

Comment: I appreciate the criticism. Performance tuning is an iterative process and I simply pointed out the first thing that jumped out to me. I certainly should have done a better analysis of the code and provided a more helpful answer.